# How to improve admin controllers used for crud

Tags: zend-framework, coding-style

I use Zend Framework and in my application admin is mostly used for CRUD operations.
I don't use zend form, and I want to keep it that way if possible, but I think that my code is not good at all, and that it can be improved allot so I am asking nicely you how to organize better this class (since all my classes look prety much the same)...

Here is the code:

http://pastie.org/2422147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

honestly the improvement would be to use Zend_Form. What is you reasoning for not using Zend_Form? If it is that you cannot get the custom look and feel you require using decorators, there are ways to leverage zend_Form without mucking with that stuff.

`Sample Admin CRUD Controller (for hierarchical categories)
    

class StoreAdmin_CategoryController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    protected $_flashMessenger = null;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->_flashMessenger = $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger');
    $this->initView();
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_forward('list');
    }

    public function listAction()
    {
        $table_category = new Store_Model_DbTable_Category();

        $obj_select         = $table_category->build_select(array(), array('order_by' => 'ASC'));
        $arr_categories = $table_category->fetch_all_objects($obj_select);

        $table_category = new Store_Model_DbTable_Category();
        $hierarchy          = $table_category->get_hierarchy(NULL);

        $this->view->assign('arr_categories', $arr_categories);
        $this->view->assign('hierarchy', $hierarchy);
    }

    public function createAction()
    {
        $form = new StoreAdmin_Form_Category();

        if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
        {
            if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()))
            {
                $table_category = new Store_Model_DbTable_Category();
                $category = $table_category->get();

                $category->set_name($form->getValue('name'));
                $category->set_slug($form->getValue('slug'));
                $category->set_description($form->getValue('description'));
                $category->set_order_by($form->getValue('order_by'));
                $category->set_id_parent($form->getValue('id_parent'));
                $category->set_date_created(time());
                $category->set_date_modified(time());

                $table_category->save($category);

                $this->_helper->FlashMessenger(array('success' => sprintf("Category: %s was successfully created!", $category->get_name())));

                $this->_redirect('/store-admin/category/list');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->_helper->FlashMessenger(array('error' => "Errors! Correct the errors in the form below"));
            }
        }

        $this->view->assign('form_category', $form);
    }

    public function updateAction()
    {
        $id_category = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id_category');
        if(empty($id_category))
        {
            throw new Zend_Exception('Error: Category ID Missing from request');
        }

        $form = new StoreAdmin_Form_Category();
        $form->removeOption($id_category);

        $table_category = new Store_Model_DbTable_Category();
        $category = $table_category->get($id_category);

        if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
        {
            if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()))
            {
                $category->set_name($form->getValue('name'));
                $category->set_slug($form->getValue('slug'));
                $category->set_description($form->getValue('description'));
                $category->set_order_by($form->getValue('order_by'));
                $category->set_id_parent($form->getValue('id_parent') ? $form->getValue('id_parent') : NULL);
                $category->set_date_modified(time());

                $table_category->save($category);

                $this->_helper->FlashMessenger(array('success' => sprintf("Category: %s was successfully updated!", $category->get_name())));

                $this->_redirect('/store-admin/category/list');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->_helper->FlashMessenger(array('error' => "Errors! Correct the errors in the form below"));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $form->populate($category->to_array());
        }

        $this->view->assign('form_category', $form);
        $this->view->assign('category', $category);
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
        $id_category = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id_category');
        if(empty($id_category))
        {
            throw new Zend_Exception('Error: Category ID Missing from request');
        }

        $table_category = new Store_Model_DbTable_Category();
        $category = $table_category->get($id_category);
        $table_category->destroy($category);

        $this->_helper->FlashMessenger(array('success' => "Category was successfully deleted!"));

        $this->_redirect('/store-admin/category/list');
    }
}`



`Sample create view`

```
<div class="span-24">
    <a href="/store-admin/category/list">List</a>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->form_category->getAction(); ?>" method="<?php echo $this->form_category->getMethod(); ?>">
        <h2>Create a Category</h2>
        <p>
            <?php echo $this->form_category->getElement('name')->renderLabel(); ?>
            <br>
            <?php echo $this->form_category->getElement('name')->renderViewHelper(); ?>
            <?php echo (NULL != ($errors = $this->form_category->getElement('name')->getMessages()) ? $this->formErrors($errors) : ''); ?>
        </p>

        <p>
            <?php echo $this->form_category->getElement('slug')->renderLabel(); ?>
            <br>
            <?php echo $this->form_category->getElement('slug')->renderViewHelper(); ?>
            <?php echo (NULL != ($errors = $this->form_category->getElement('slug')->getMessages()) ? $this->formErrors($errors) : ''); ?>
        </p>

        <p>
            <?php echo $this->form_category->getElement('id_parent')->renderLabel(); ?>
            <br>
            <?php echo $this->form_category->getElement('id_parent')->renderViewHelper(); ?>
            <?php echo (NULL != ($errors = $this->form_category->getElement('id_parent')->getMessages()) ? $this->formErrors($errors) : ''); ?>
        </p>

        <p>
            <?php echo $this->form_category->getElement('description')->renderLabel(); ?>
            <br>
            <?php echo $this->form_category->getElement('description')->renderViewHelper(); ?>
            <?php echo (NULL != ($errors = $this->form_category->getElement('description')->getMessages()) ? $this->formErrors($errors) : ''); ?>
        </p>

        <p>
            <?php echo $this->form_category->getElement('order_by')->renderLabel(); ?>
            <br>
            <?php echo $this->form_category->getElement('order_by')->renderViewHelper(); ?>
            <?php echo (NULL != ($errors = $this->form_category->getElement('order_by')->getMessages()) ? $this->formErrors($errors) : ''); ?>
        </p>

        <p>
            <?php echo $this->form_category->getElement('submit_category')->renderViewHelper(); ?>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            $('#name').change( slugify ).keyup( slugify );
        }
    );

    function slugify()
    {
        text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        text = text.replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9,&\s]+/ig, '');
        text = text.replace(/-/gi, "_");
        text = text.replace(/\s/gi, "-");

        $('#slug').val(text);
    }
</script>
```

`Sample Category Form`

```
<?php
class StoreAdmin_Form_Category extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setMethod(self::METHOD_POST);

        $element = $this->createElement('hidden', 'id_category');
        $element->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
        $element->removeDecorator('label');
        $this->addElement($element);

        $element = $this->createElement('text', 'name');
        $element->setLabel('Name');
        $element->setRequired(TRUE);
        $element->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
        $element->setAttrib('class', 'text');
        $this->addElement($element);

        $element = $this->createElement('text', 'slug');
        $element->setLabel('Slug');
        $element->setRequired(TRUE);
        $element->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
        $element->setAttrib('class', 'text');
        $this->addElement($element);

        $element = $this->createElement('textarea', 'description');
        $element->setLabel('Description');
        $element->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
        $element->setAttrib('class', '');
        $this->addElement($element);

        $table_category = new Store_Model_DbTable_Category();
        $options = $table_category->get_tree_options(NULL, '', array(NULL => ''));
        $element = $this->createElement('select', 'id_parent');
        $element->setLabel('Parent Category');
        $element->setRequired(FALSE);
        $element->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
        $element->addMultiOptions($options);
        $this->addElement($element);

        $element = $this->createElement('text', 'order_by');
        $element->setLabel('Display Order');
        $element->setRequired(TRUE);
        $element->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
        $element->setAttrib('class', 'text');
        $this->addElement($element);

        $element = $this->createElement('submit', 'submit_category');
        $element->setLabel('Submit');
        $element->setRequired(TRUE);
        $element->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
        $element->removeDecorator('label');
        $this->addElement($element);
    }

    /**
     * Makes sure that a Category cannot become its own parent (causing a rescursion error)
     */
    public function removeOption($id_category)
    {
        $this->removeElement('id_parent');

        $table_category = new Store_Model_DbTable_Category();
        $options                = $table_category->get_tree_options(NULL, '', array(NULL => ''));

        if(array_key_exists($id_category, $options))
        {
            unset($options[$id_category]);
        }

        $element = $this->createElement('select', 'id_parent');
        $element->setLabel('Parent Category');
        $element->setRequired(FALSE);
        $element->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
        $element->addMultiOptions($options);
        $this->addElement($element);
    }
}
```

Zend_Form greatly simplifies crud controllers. More importantly, it is the accepted practice  to use them if you are going to be building apps on ZF.

Comment: .In case we wanna use a RIA framework such as extjs, then zend_form will be partially useless specially if forms are created on the fly using dom manipulations.in that case,would you recommend using zend_form at least for form validations,processing and filtering or not?

Comment: If you could give me an example of the kinds of dom manipulations, I would be able to answer better. My answer was a specific critique of the controller you pastied in your post. though if you put all possible fields into the zend_Form with validators, you can validate/filter only the fields that were posted using $form->isValidPartial(). This would allow you to process the form using native Zend_Form, while giving you maximum ability to perform dom manipulations with JS. Post a more specific use-case?

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. Thing why I am not using Zend_Form is because I don't want to deal with the design at all, from you code it's look like much more job to do, and I am not sure, can I increase the speed of development process, because in this small project key is to deliver the app until deadline, and quality is less important.

I wan't to speed up crud operations, and to code very small amount of code for that part. I believe that you know what I mean.

If you have some general suggestions, I am looking forward to talk with you.

Comment: Ok, honestly, it sounds like you are trying to get to market fast at the expense of quality. Which is fine i guess (not really).. But in that case, why post a question about how to improve a controller's code if quality isn't the goal?

Comment: Hm, I completely agree with you, and I will accept your answer. This is kind to complicated for small and cheep projects, and I asked because I wanted to add some small improvements, and to speed up more development process if possible